# let $X$ be Hausdorff and $Y\subseteq X$ is dense and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous prove that $f$ is identity function

Tags: general-topology

let $X$ be Hausdorff and $Y\subseteq X$ is dense and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous and for each $a\in Y$, $f\left(a\right)=a$ prove that $f$ is identity function

Comment: Do you mean $f: X \rightarrow X$?

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) \neq x$ for some $x$ then there exist disjoint open  sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ such that $f(x) \in U$ and $x \in V$. $f^{-1}(U) \cap V$ is an open set and it is not empty since it contains $x$. Hence this set must intersect the dense set $Y$. But then there exist $a \in Y$ such that $f(a) \in U, a \in V$ which makes $f(a) \neq a$.